# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [name]) from several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, distinct

I can perform the following SQL Server selection of distinct (or non-repeating names) from a column in one table like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Name]) FROM [MyTable]
```

But what if I have more than one table (all these tables contain the name field called [Name]) and I need to know the count of non-repeating names in two or more tables.

If I run something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Name]) FROM [MyTable1], [MyTable2], [MyTable3]
```

I get an error, "Ambiguous column name 'Name'".

PS. All three tables [MyTable1], [MyTable2], [MyTable3] are a product of a previous selection.

Comment: Do you want count from all three tables? or just from one of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-repeating names"?

Comment: OK, say, MyTable1's [Name] column has values: "John", "Mary", "John", "Aaron". MyTable2's [Name] column has values: "Mary", "Aaron", "Aaron", "Mary". MyTable3's [Name] column has values: "John", "Mary", "John", "John". I need to get the count, such as: "John" = 5 times, "Mary" = 4 times, "Aaron" = 3 times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After the clarification, use:

```
  SELECT x.name, COUNT(x.[name])
    FROM (SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable2]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable3]) x
GROUP BY x.name
```

If I understand correctly, use:

```
  SELECT x.name, COUNT(DISTINCT x.[name])
    FROM (SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable2]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT [name]
            FROM [MyTable3]) x
GROUP BY x.name
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates; `UNION ALL` will not, and is faster for it.

Comment: I think you have covered all options now :) +1

Comment: And, the UNION ALL is the right way to go, no matter which solution is used :)

Comment: Guys, I apologize for misleading you. I'm just learning SQL. I'm also curious, will this code handle names in a case-sensitive matter, i.e. "John" and "john" count as 2, or as 1?

Comment: @ahmd0 - case sensitivity is based on your server-level Collation settings.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` on the grouping key will always result in `1`.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT:  Had to change after seeing recent comment.

Does this give you what you want?  This gives a count for each person after combining the rows from all tables.

```
SELECT [NAME], COUNT(*) as TheCount
FROM
    (
     SELECT [Name] FROM [MyTable1]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT [Name] FROM [MyTable2]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT [Name] FROM [MyTable3]
     ) AS [TheNames]
GROUP BY [NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
SELECT x.name, SUM(x.cnt)
FROM ( SELECT [name], COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM [MyTable]
       GROUP BY [name]
     UNION ALL
       SELECT [name], COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM [MyTable2]
       GROUP BY [name]
     UNION ALL
       SELECT [name], COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM [MyTable3]
       GROUP BY [name]
     ) AS x
GROUP BY x.name
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have **different amounts of columns per table**, like:

- table1 has 3 columns,
- table2 has 2 columns,
- table3 has 1 column

And you want to count the amount of distinct values of different column names, what it was useful to me in **AthenaSQL** was to use `CROSS JOIN` since your output would be only one row, it would be just 1 combination:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name1) as amt_name1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT name2) as amt_name2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT name3) as amt_name3,
FROM table1 ) t1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name4) as amt_name4,
        COUNT(DISTINCT name5) as amt_name5,
        MAX(t3.amt_name6) as amt_name6
 FROM table2
 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name6) as amt_name6
  FROM table3) t3) t2
```

Would return a table with one row and their counts:

```
amt_name1 | amt_name2 | amt_name3 | amt_name4 | amt_name5 | amt_name6
    4123  |    675    |    564    |    2346   |   18667   |    74567
```