# MySQL Select Distinct values from 2 tables and Count

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have 2 tables, both of them with a varchar(10) field called "palin" and I want to MySQL-query to receive all the different "palin" values from the 2 tables and count how many lines in total have each "palin" value, like:

table1: id1/palin1, id2/palin2, id3/palin3

table2: id1/palin1, id2/palin3, id3/palin4

Result:palin1/2, palin2/1, palin3/2, palin4/1

I have done it 2 queries (one for each table) by using "SELECT DISTINCT palin,COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY palin", then "SELECT DISTINCT palin,COUNT(*) FROM table2 GROUP BY palin" and then sum both COUNTS, but I´d need to do it all in one query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also did this to get all the different "palin" values from both tables, but with no COUNT: "SELECT DISTINCT palin FROM (SELECT palin FROM table1 UNION SELECT palin FROM table2) t GROUP BY palin"

Comment: I just found the answer in another topic, thanks anyway and sorry:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712127/select-countdistinct-name-from-several-tables?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It do not understand why you want to merge to distinct values from 2 tables but try the following:

```
select distinct palin, count(palin) from table1 union all select distinct palin, count(palin) from table2 group by palin;
```

Union all does filter out the same records, union does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The exact query seems to be: 
"SELECT x.palin, COUNT(x.palin) FROM (SELECT palin FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT palin FOM table2) x GROUP BY x.palin"

Answer (score 0):

The exact query seems to be: "SELECT x.palin, COUNT(x.palin) FROM (SELECT palin FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT palin FOM table2) x GROUP BY x.palin"

Thanks!